# Validacion de dato en C#

Tags: c#, bucles

Buenas Alguien me puede ayudar aqui por favor estoy un poco confundido con un ciclo.

Lo que intento hacer es que mi programa siga preguntando mientras el usuario introduzca un valor que sea numerico, al principio lo hace todo bien pero luego no me sigue con el codigo solo me termina el programa y hay mas lineas de codigos.

```
int Figura;
        var Altura = 0.0;
        var Base = 0.0;
        var valido = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Introduzca que el numero para la figura que desea calcular " +
            "\n las opciones son:\n1: Area del cuadrado" + "\n2: Area de rectangulo" + "\n3: Area de un triangulo" +
            "\n4: Area de una circuferencia");
        Figura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (Figura)
        {
            case 1:         
                Console.WriteLine("Ha elegido la opcion Area de Triangulo");
                    
                    
                    while (!valido)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIntroduzca la Altura por favor");
                    var num = (Console.ReadLine());
                    valido = double.TryParse(num, out Altura);
                    Console.WriteLine("Solo se admiten valores numericos");
                    }
                while (!valido)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIntroduzca la Base por favor");
                    var num2 = (Console.ReadLine());
                    valido = double.TryParse(num2, out Base);
                    Console.WriteLine("Solo se admiten valores numericos");
                }

                double resultado = Base * Altura / 2;
                Console.WriteLine("\nEl area del triangulo cuya base es: " + Base + " y altura es: " + Altura + " es: " + resultado);

                break;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En que momento le decis que vuelva al principio para que vuelva  apreguntar???

Comment: usas la misma variable para los dos ciclos, cuando el primer ciclo cambiar el valor, el segundo no entra.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Si me di cuenta luego gracias, ya di con la solución gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres quedarte en un loop validado no usas ninguna variable solo pones un `while(true)` y sales con el `break`, algo como esto

```
 while (true)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("\nIntroduzca la Altura por favor");
     var num = Console.ReadLine();

     if(double.TryParse(num, out Altura)){
          break;
     } 

     Console.WriteLine("Solo se admiten valores numericos");
 }

  //resto codigo
```

solo si puede parsear sera que ingrese en el if y el break hara que salga del while, sino continuara en el ciclo hasta que se rompa

Comment: Muchas Graciaas @Leandro Tuttini